# How to convert float to int without losing information?

Tags: arduino, signal-processing

I am currently working on an audio based project on Arduino. The input is received (via ADC) is  of type double and I have to perform some math operations on the data. I then need to output the audio. The issue however, is that PWM output register (based on AVR) accepts ints.

Hence, is there any way to convert this float to int without losing data?

Comment: ATmega ADC outputs a 10-bit integer. What data do you lose? Please give an example of a conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Generic float to int conversion will almost always lose information, unless the input is quantized and the maximum dynamic range of the input and the results of all subsequent arithmetic operations are limited to 2^n for some n less than the size of your integer.

Note that noise shaping (filtered dithering) of the quantization noise may help reduce some of the information loss, depending on the signal input.